# Wheel type datepicker style not working properly

Tags: date, swiftui, datepicker, customization

I am integrating date picker in my project, the date picker style is wheel type(.datePickerStyle(.wheel)). but the months are not setting in the inline. is the issue involved with language or the UI?

Edit:  I tried the same code without the locale in an empty ptoject and thats is working fine, while this one not working..!!

What is wrong here?[image: issue screenshot added here]

```
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            DatePicker(
                "",
                selection: $selectedDate,
                in: Date()...,
                displayedComponents: [.date]
            ).environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: Singleton.shared.retrieveString(for: .selectedLanguage)))
            .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Button("Cancel".localized) {
                    isDatePickerShown = false
                }
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    onDateSelected()
                    isDatePickerShown = false
                }) {
                    Text("OK".localized)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding(5)
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(width:365, height: 275, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .shadow(radius: 5)
```

Comment: Can you show the "working fine" case? I don't see anything wrong with this picture

Comment: The same code I used in an empty project, it is working fine. I am using RTL context in my project is that an issue here?